# %post_id%-%postname% to %year%/%monthnum%/%postname% redirection on new domain via htacess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a .co.uk site with 2years age and that have %post_id%-%postname% url structure. My second .com site have %year%/%monthnum%/%postname% url structure.
Now i want to move my .co.uk site to this .com site and redirect all urls to the new .com url structure. That means i want to permanently redirect %post_id%-%postname% urls to %year%/%monthnum%/%postname% urls using .htacess.

Can someone help me out with this? Once i have the solution i will start migrating from .co.uk to .com domain.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In order to do this you to be able to get all the parameters you are redirecting with from the original request... I doubt you can do this and you will probably need to write a script to take post_ids and get the info needed forward requests to your new site.

Comment: Any other way via htaccess.? Please ....